# Проверка: заполнено ли поле

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите, что вставить ,чтобы проверяла заполнено ли поле? а то отправляет пустые из сафари и IE.  Сейчас стоит на пустоту. а как сделать чтобы проверяла заполнено ли поле

```
<input id="phone" maxlength="20" name="phone" type="text" placeholder='Введите телефон' pattern='8[0-9]{10}' required title="Формат (с цифры 8 и без пробелов): 89061111111" class="placeholder">
```

Вот код скрипта

```
$(function(){
    /* Mail */
    $('.mail').submit(function(e){
    if($.trim($('phone_field_selector').val()) === '') return false;
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).children('.send').replaceWith("<h5 class='nomargbut'>Спасибо за заявку!</h5><h5 class='nomargbut'>Мы свяжемся с Вами в течение 30 минут</h5>");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sends.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "true"){
                    $('.back, .hide').hide().before('<div class="success">Спасибо за заявку! Мы свяжемся с Вами в течение дня.</div>');
                    setTimeout("$('.success').fadeOut()", 3000);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: в IE что выдает вот это: $.trim($('phone_field_selector').val()) ?

Comment: так вообще ни с какого браузера не реагирует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас сейчас на сколько понимаю валидация на пустоту и формат телефона происходит средствами HTML5, которые, как бы мягко говоря еще не всеми браузерами нормально поддерживаются (в всяком случае версии постарше), соответственно все еще есть достаточно много случаев когда она не срабатывает. Я немного упростил ваш код (убрал атрибуты валидации из input т.к. мой браузер их отрабатывал корректно, верните их обратно как они сейчас у вас, и убрал длинное текстовое сообщение, также верните его) и поменял проверку - в случае пустого поля вылазит alert - измените это действие на необходимое вам

[линк на код](http://jsfiddle.net/vz6VU/6/)

Comment: спасибо, но когда даже заполненое поле вылазит empty в сафари

Comment: Обновил код проверьте, вы как откуда-то переписали "phone_field_selector" так у себя и не поменяли на актуальный селектор

Comment: Большое человеческое благодарствие!!!+1

Comment: еще такой вопрос. Если форм много то он только самую первую проверяет все ок. А если начинаешь со второй формы то всегда пишет empty

Comment: все дело в том что проверяется id="phone" (видимо так у вас в текущей версии). В HTML id, по определению, должен быть уникальным на текущей странице и если даже не так на самом деле, то всеравно выбирается только первый элемент, который встречается на странице (вот и ваша проверка только первого элемента). 

Решением может быть смена у элемента input id="phone" на class="phone" и при проверке проверять только тот input, который находится в этой форме. 

обновленный пример: http://jsfiddle.net/vz6VU/12/